# osascript set volume isn't working via ssh

Tags: ssh, set, volume, osascript, remote-management

here is my situation.

**User A** is currently logged on **Computer A**.

**User B** logs into **Computer A** via ssh.

**User B** runs via terminal a osascript (`osascript -e 'set volume 0'`)

here is my error log:

```
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Error>: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Error>: This user is not allowed access to the window system right now.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
2015-10-20 13:25:17.196 osascript[29389:1503684] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-10-20 13:25:17.197 osascript[29389:1503684] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-10-20 13:25:17.197 osascript[29389:1503684] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-10-20 13:25:17.197 osascript[29389:1503684] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
Oct 20 13:25:17  osascript[29389] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
```

**Side notes**
User B is set as admin

Once upon a time, I recall executing this situation before without any errors. Not sure if this is a *ARD setting* with privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an alternative which seems to work...

If I add

`sudo -u username` before the `osascript -e` command, then it works.

**example**

```
sudo -u username osascript -e 'set volume 0'
```

from what a read, seems that apple does not allow users to *open* applications via ssh session while another user is logged in. Must be logged in as the current user to run `osascripts`, otherwise, add the following command `sudo -u username`