# How to set volume on OSX at login prompt?

Tags: macos, volume, osascript

I want to do the same thing as [osascript set volume isn't working via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247260/osascript-set-volume-isnt-working-via-ssh), except that no user is logged (sshd is launched at startup without login).